# UITableView crashes on scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am facing a problem in table view, the application crashes as soon as i scrolldown and try to select a row. 
Error I am getting in console is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Please help me to understand why i am getting this error, I dont think there is any nil element in my array, let me show you the code

I have created a SelectContactViewController in which a user can select number of contact so the files are

SelectContactController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>



@interface SelectContactController :UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *selectedImageIds;
    NSArray *selectContacts;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *selectContacts;
```

and the implementation file SelectContactController.m

```
#import "SelectContactController.h"



@interface SelectContactController ()

@end

@implementation SelectContactController
@synthesize selectContacts;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    selectContacts = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    selectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    contactDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    selectedImageIds = [appDelegate selectedImageIds];



    [self getAddressbookData];


}
#pragma mark - Address book Methods

-(void)getAddressbookData
{
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 60000
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
#else
    CFErrorRef *error = nil;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
#endif

    NSArray * people;


    BOOL accessGranted = [self __addressBookAccessStatus:addressBook];

    if (accessGranted) {

        people = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        // Do whatever you need with thePeople...

    }
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    NSMutableArray *contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) {
        ABRecordRef record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex((__bridge CFArrayRef)(people), i);
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *fullName = nil;



        if (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst)
            fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
        else
            fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", lastName, firstName];

        [contactArray addObject:fullName];

        //
        // Phone Numbers
        //
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFIndex phoneNumberCount = ABMultiValueGetCount( phoneNumbers );


        NSMutableArray *numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for ( CFIndex k=0; k<phoneNumberCount; k++ )
        {
            CFStringRef phoneNumberLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex( phoneNumbers, k );
            CFStringRef phoneNumberValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex( phoneNumbers, k );
            CFStringRef phoneNumberLocalizedLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel( phoneNumberLabel );
            // converts "_$!<Work>!$_" to "work" and "_$!<Mobile>!$_" to "mobile"

            // Find the ones you want here
            //
           // NSLog(@"-----PHONE ENTRY -> name:%@ :  %@ : %@", fullName, phoneNumberLocalizedLabel, phoneNumberValue );
            [numbersArray addObject:CFBridgingRelease(phoneNumberValue)];

            CFRelease(phoneNumberLocalizedLabel);
            CFRelease(phoneNumberLabel);
            CFRelease(phoneNumberValue);
        }

       // NSLog(@"phone numbers %@", numbersArray);
        [contactDictionary setObject:numbersArray forKey:fullName];

        CFRelease(record);

    }

    selectContacts = contactArray;
   // NSLog(@"dictionary of array %@", contactDictionary);

    //NSLog(@"contacts count %d", [selectContacts count]);
}

-(BOOL)__addressBookAccessStatus:(ABAddressBookRef) addressBook
{
    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;

    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        // dispatch_release(sema);
    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }
    return accessGranted;
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"select content count %d", [selectContacts count]);
    return [selectContacts count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.selectContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: is this even being called ..   `[self getAddressbookData];` ?

Comment: yes it is called and working properly

Comment: Can you step thru the method `getAddressbookData` to get the line where it's crashing?

Answer (score 2):

The exception message is quite clear: You are trying to insert a `nil` value into an array. The bug is probably in the line

```
[numbersArray addObject:CFBridgingRelease(phoneNumberValue)];
```

Check if `phoneNumberValue` is nil before adding the object. Another good idea is to use the debugger to find the problem. Add an exception breakpoint before running the app in Xcode.

Comment: I am not using numbers array to fill the UIView table

Comment: @PuneetBharti The bug is probably only loosely connected to the table view. As I said, the exception is message is quite clear, you are inserting `nil` into an array. The line with the `numbersArray` is the only place in the posted code where this can happen.

Comment: you are right there is nil value in numbersArray, but my problem is with selectContact may have nil value that's why its crashing

Comment: In the code you posted, there's no way a nil value can try to be inserted into `contactArray`.

Answer (score 0):

i think in this case debugging would be good solution. So use break point on this line and let me know in which index it is crashing.

```
   cell.textLabel.text = [self.selectContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

With `selectContacts = [[NSArray alloc] init];` or `selectContacts = contactArray;` the setter is not used. It should be either `self.selectContacts` when assigning or do `@synthesize selectContacts = _selectContacts;` and then use only _selectContacts only within the .m file.

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible that for few numbers you have not provided the first name and last name details so you must try this :

```
if (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst)

        fullName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
     else
       fullName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@, %@", lastName, firstName];
  if([fullName length]>0)

        [contactArray addObject:fullName];
```

Comment: This can't be the culprit since `stringWithFormat:` will always return a non-nil value.